# How to resolve the Crosswalk SSL Certificate Error

Tags: cordova, ssl, crosswalk

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(XWalkView view, ValueCallback<Boolean> callback, SslError error) {
    callback.onReceiveValue(true);
}
```

I've changed this code in `XWalkCordovaResourceClient` class. It allows ignore self signed certificates in 1.7.2 version crosswalk. After I updated crosswalk version to > 1.7.2 it throws exception that `Request was denied for security.`

How can I resolve this SSL error?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: no i use 1.7.2 version now.